# Insted of repeating the same thing again and again can I use a loop in my code here? HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, image, loops, repeat

I have 25 images all together.

Can I somehow use a loop in order to make things easier for myself. I do not want to repeat the same code again and again like I have done below.

```css
span.boxer1 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.boxer1 span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.boxers li:hover span.boxer1 {
  opacity: 1;
}
span.boxer2 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.boxer2 span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.boxers li:hover span.boxer2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.boxer3 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.boxer3 span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.boxers li:hover span.boxer3 {
  opacity: 1;
}

span.boxer4 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.boxer4 span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.boxers li:hover span.boxer4 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Use the same class for all spans???? or use another selector like `ul.boxers li > span` ???

Comment: Can't you just use a common class for `.boxer1`, `.boxer2`, `.boxer3`? The idea of classes is that they're reusable.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You know You can use multiple styles in one element?

```
<div id="myid1needforsomethingelse" class="liketable300 topalign myfont14">
 <span class="mypadding2 mymargin3 myheadersbig"> content </span>
</div>
<div id="myid2needforsomethingelse" class="liketable300 topalign myfont12">
 <span class="mypadding2 mymargin3 mycontentmedium"> content </span>
</div>
```

So just divide your css that repeat in classes and just use in repeat, I **could** be easier than writing style for each and any div/span and under-div and under-span out there :D

Comment: @DaniP of course class, not style :)
Benny didn't said anything about ID's so it was just example, and I'm currently in heavy use of it.

Answer (score 0):

A 'class' can be used on multiple elements to apply the same CSS rules to each element.

An 'ID' is a unique identifier that should only be used on one element.

In your case you want to add a class to each of your elements and set your CSS rules on that class so that they will be applied to each element e.g.

```
.myclass {
    background: #000;
}

<div class="myclass"></div>

<div class="myclass"></div>

<div class="myclass"></div>

<div class="myclass"></div>
```

In the above example the rule set in the CSS for .myclass will be applied to all four elements.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - as far as I can tell there is no difference in these classes, so you could just use a common class for all of them and set the styling once.

That said, if you are using some script to loop to create the images, presumably they are also in some form of other container, in which case you could use an nth child designation in the CSS if you need to differentiate.

```
div.boxercontainer:nth-child(1) {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write common css rules for some selector with comma like :

```
span.boxer1, span.boxer2 {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 275px;
  opacity: 0;
}

span.boxer1 span, span.boxer2 span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.boxers li:hover span.boxer1, ul.boxers li:hover span.boxer2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In case you need to set different css for example for span.boxer1, you can write this :

```
span.boxer1 { width : 300px;} // in this case the latest css-rule will be applied to element, so width:300 will override width:250 which are upper in css file
```

This should override existing common css https://jsfiddle.net/q83ojcbq/

---

Or like @Bri.H. already answer You can use same rules(css-classes) for different elements